# Running time of the number of steps to find GCD(a,b)

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

Let $t_n$ be the largest (worst case) number of steps being used to find the greatest common divisor $GCD(a,b)$ when $n\geq a\geq b >0$.

Is it true that the reason why $t_n$ is $\mathcal{O}(n)$ and not $\mathcal{O}(1)$ because the number of steps can never be larger than the smallest integer in $GCD(a,b)$?

And the reason why the worst case running time isn't $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is because it can never take constant time to find the number of steps?

***Note:*** Say I want to find GCD(13,8)

\begin{align}
13 & = 1 \cdot 8 + 5 \tag{step 1} \\[0.5em] 
8  & =  1 \cdot 5 + 3 \tag{step 2} \\[0.5em]
5 & = 1 \cdot 3 + 2 \tag{step 3} \\[0.5em]
3 & = 1 \cdot 2 + 1 \tag{step 4} \\[0.5em]
2 & = 1 \cdot 2 + 0 \tag{step 5}
\end{align}

In this case $GCD(13,8) = 1$, but the number of steps would be 5, i.e $t_n = 5$

Comment: The worst case for the euclidean algorithm are consecutive Fibonacci numbers, and they grow exponentially. So the worst case is of the order of the logarithm $n$.

Comment: @Arthur It's not the worst case for the Euclidean algorithm. The worst case here is the number of steps to find GCD

Comment: And the euclidean algorithm is the standard way of finding the GCD. Or are you using some other method?

Comment: @Arthur I'm pretty sure it's the Euclidean algorithm I am using. I added an example of what I mean

Comment: And the worst case is two consecutive Fibonacci numbers. Just there you used $8$ and $13$, for instance. That's the lowest $5$-step. The next $5$-step pairs are $(11,18)$ (consecutive Lucas numbers) and $(11,19)$, but they don't matter for worst-case analysis. The first $6$-step is $(13,21)$, another Fibonacci pair, which is a pattern that continues.

Comment: @Arthur Then is the time complexity of $t_n$ $\mathcal{O}(n)$?